# For a new class should i upload meta.xml to github?

Tags: xml, git, github

When I write a new class and need to push the class to svn/git do I need to upload the `-meta.xml` file also? or just the .cls file?

Comment: what means you are using to upload the class to git or SVN?

Comment: We are using git gui.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

meta.xml files for code carries two important attributes

1)An attribute for mentioning version

2)Status of your class

Ideally it is better to checkout both to SVN so that in case one of your dev change status of the class or version ,its tracked as well.

Also very important point to note is without meta.xml file you won't be able to deploy code to PROD or any other environment

Comment: Not to mention, if you *build* from the CVS directly, it won't deploy without that tiny little xml file.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks .Yes without that xml your code is like a bird without wing

Comment: You should definetly keep this in git.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava A [Kiwi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwi) is a bird without wings. It's still a bird :)

Comment: @DanielBallinger They are super creatures like you and I wont be shocked if someday you will find way to deploy apex without meta.xml file :)

Comment: @MohithShrivastava touche :)